# KeyError: 1 During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which look like:

```
df:
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|Text_en                                            | pos_score   |  neg_score |  sent_score| 
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
|  inspir afternoon bang stori ahmad sahroni v AS...|  0.000      |  0.0       |  0         |    
|                                                   |  0.000      |  0.0       |  0         |      
|  some drastic measur taken manag bodi temperatu.  |  1.625      |  0.5       |  1         |     
|  ahmad sahroni tu                                 |  0.000      |  0.0       |  0         |    
|  busi success mudah legisl mandat who make inte...|  1.125      |  0.0       |  1         |   
+---------------------------------------------------+-------------+------------+------------+
```

I want to generate/assigned positive text, negative text, neutral text for further processing using this code:

```py
pos_text=""
neg_text=""
neut_text=""

for i in range(len(df_copy.index)):
    if(df_copy.loc[i]["sent_score"]==1):
        pos_text+=df_copy.loc[i]["Text_en"]
    elif(df_copy.loc[i]["sent_score"]==-1):
        neg_text+=df_copy.loc[i]["Text_en"]
    else:
        neut_text+=df_copy.loc[i]["Text_en"]

list_text = [pos_text,neg_text,neut_text]
```

But it raised an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2645             try:
-> 2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-8ff17d5161f0> in <module>
      4 
      5 for i in range(len(df_copy.index)):
----> 6     if(df_copy.loc[i]["sent_score"]==1):
      7         pos_text+=df_copy.loc[i]["Text"]
      8     elif(df_copy.loc[i]["sent_score"]==-1):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1765 
   1766             maybe_callable = com.apply_if_callable(key, self.obj)
-> 1767             return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
   1768 
   1769     def _is_scalar_access(self, key: Tuple):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1962         # fall thru to straight lookup
   1963         self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1964         return self._get_label(key, axis=axis)
   1965 
   1966 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _get_label(self, label, axis)
    622             raise IndexingError("no slices here, handle elsewhere")
    623 
--> 624         return self.obj._xs(label, axis=axis)
    625 
    626     def _get_loc(self, key: int, axis: int):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in xs(self, key, axis, level, drop_level)
   3535             loc, new_index = self.index.get_loc_level(key, drop_level=drop_level)
   3536         else:
-> 3537             loc = self.index.get_loc(key)
   3538 
   3539             if isinstance(loc, np.ndarray):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.Int64HashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 1
```

Anyway, at first, I run my code it worked like charm then I did some cleaning like dropping some duplicates rows then when I tried to run again I got those error

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], and clarify what exactly your question is. Also, that loop looks unidiomatic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its that [i] part for sure, because that's where it breaks. df_copy.loc[1] is an error there is no [1]. So I need to reset my index using

```py
df_copy=df_copy.reset_index(drop=True)
```

It worked like a charm

Answer (score 3):

The application of df.loc[i] expects "i" to be a valid index value in your pandas DataFrame. If you have dropped some rows (e.g., duplicates), you have removed some of the indices and thus they are not in your DataFrame index anymore.

Apply df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True) to generate a fresh index with consecutive numbers in your clean DataFrame.

Answer (score 2):

You generally don't want to loop over a dataframe in this way. Instead, use loc to query and then do something with the results.

```
pos_text = df_copy.loc[df['sent_score'] == 1, 'Text_en']
neg_text = df_copy.loc[df['sent_score'] == -1, 'Text_en']
neut_text = df_copy.loc[df['sent_score'] == 0, 'Text_en']
```